# Integrating Quill text editor in an Angular application

Tags: angular, quill, ngx-quill

I am learning how to create blogging websites. I tried a simple example first. But the text editor is not showing up on my screen. I installed Quill with `npm install --save quill@1.3.6 ngx-quill` command. My `app.component.html` is very simple.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand ml-auto mr-auto" href="#">Quill JS Editor with Angular</a>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row pt-5">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <form [formGroup]="editorForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="editor">
            <h3>Editor</h3>
          </label>
          <quill-editor></quill-editor>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 bg-light p-4">
      <h3>Output</h3>
      <p class="my-5"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Actually it should look like.
[image]

I have also imported `FormGroup` and `FormControl` from `@angular/forms` in my `app.component.ts` which contains the following code.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  editorForm: FormGroup;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.editorForm = new FormGroup({
      'editor': new FormControl(null)
    })
  }
}
```

But I am getting this error. [image]

The entire project is on [github](https://github.com/tmtanzeel/angular-blog-three). Please tell me what else I am missing in this project.

Comment: Hi, i'm trying to implement ngx-quill but I'm getting an error for forRoot() i,e. Property 'forRoot' does not exist on type 'typeof QuillModule' . My angular version is 4.11.10 and ngx-quill is 3.6.0. Any guidance to resolve this ? Thanks

Comment: @PragatiKerur, Did you add `QuillModule.forRoot()` in your `imports:[]` array of module class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means you haven't configured that library properly, particularly you should be importing `QuillModule.forRoot()` so that all delivered with this library providers are properly initialized.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    QuillModule.forRoot(),
...
```

Btw, this is how [documentation tells](https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill#for-standard-webpack-angular-cli-and-tsc-builds) us to do it.

Comment: I have done this also. Here is my `app.module.ts`.

`import { QuillModule} from 'ngx-quill';`

 ` imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    QuillModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ].......

Comment: Please do note `.forRoot()` call

Comment: thanks for this. It worked. But please tell me why `.forRoot()`. I followed a youtube video. It wasn't there but still working for that guy.

Comment: Because only with forRoot we get that config provider https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill/blob/2408e03eb8cf19b2fff33fb3fb3aeaa480d15600/src/quill.module.ts#L26 Maybe in that video that guy used old version where forRoot didn't  exist

Comment: Oh ok. Now I understand. Thanks. By the way that person is using Angular 7, and the video was published this year, Feb 2019. Here is link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sh3_k_QPGzw

Comment: In the video ngx-quill 4.6.3 was installed. You have 7 version. Now you can check changelog https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill/releases/tag/7.0.0

Answer (score 33):

Follow these steps it should work:

1- Installation:

```
 npm install ngx-quill
 npm install @angular/core
 npm install @angular/common
 npm install @angular/forms
 npm install @angular/platform-browser
 npm install quill
 npm install rxjs — peer dependencies of rxjs-quill
```

- include theme stylings: bubble.css, snow.css of quilljs in your index.html, or add them in your css/scss files with `@import` statements, or add them external stylings in your build process.

Update the angular.json file with the following code:

```
  “styles”: [
          “./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css”,
          “src/styles.css”,
          “./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.core.css”,
          “./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css”
        ],
        “scripts”: [“./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js”]
```

import it in your app.module.ts

```
   import { QuillModule } from 'ngx-quill'
```

and in the imports add it like bellow

```
 @NgModule({
  declarations:[],
  imports:[
    CommonModule,
    QuillModule.forRoot(),
  ]
 })
```

in your component.ts file you can modify the editor style like bellow code:

```
   editorStyle = {
     height: '200px'
   };
```

and in your component.html file you could call it like bellow code:

```
 <div id="quill">
                <p>Content *</p>
                <quill-editor [styles]="editorStyle" placeholder="Enter Text" [modules]="config"
                    formControlName="yourCtrlname" required>
                </quill-editor>
            </div>
```

You can also check: https://lifecoders.wordpress.com/angular/quill-rich-text-editor-setup-in-angular-7-8/

and here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-quill

Comment: Yes I just put extra details which was missing on the answer so that help some junior developers  and save times ... :)

Comment: I appreciate this gesture. :-)

Comment: npm install rxjs — peer dependencies of rxjs-quill
 is throwing error

Comment: Except `npm install rxjs — peer dependencies of rxjs-quill`, everything works out well! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @MJ X who's answer covers the most.

Today is **2021-09-13**, **Angular v11, ngx-quill 14.3.0**, recap and supplement to his/hers:

*1) Installation*

```
 npm install ngx-quill
 npm install @angular/core
 npm install @angular/common
 npm install @angular/forms
 npm install @angular/material
 npm install @angular/platform-browser
 npm install quill
 npm install bootstrap  // optional for better look.
```

*2) app.module.ts*

```
import { QuillModule } from 'ngx-quill';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [..., QuillModule.forRoot() ]
```

*3) root styles.css*

```
 @import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";  /* required */
 @import '~quill/dist/quill.core.css';
 @import '~quill/dist/quill.bubble.css';
 @import '~quill/dist/quill.snow.css';
 @import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";  /* optional for better look */
```