# Quill table with Angular, not working on edit mode

Tags: angular, quill

I have an Angular Application, I have a form and used quill-better-table (https://www.npmjs.com/package/quill-better-table)

I have added configurations mentioned here ([How do I fix this error I get whenever I try to register quill-better-table with my quill editor component in Angular 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58701585/how-do-i-fix-this-error-i-get-whenever-i-try-to-register-quill-better-table-with))
When I am in insert mode it works and generate rich text which you can past tables also inserts the data into database
when now I want to populate the data in edit mode, the rich textbox does not display the content.

```
div id="quill">
    <p>Content *</p>
    <quill-editor [styles]="editorStyle" placeholder="Enter Text" formControlName="myfieldCtrl" required>
    </quill-editor>
</div>
```

Comment: Please tell how to done two way binding in using quill..2.0.0-dev-3 in angular 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow my Answer on how to setup Quill in Angular properly here:

[Integrating Quill text editor in an Angular application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57631897/integrating-quill-text-editor-in-an-angular-application/59429710#59429710)

Next I am not sure how you setup your angular but it might be issue with DomSanitizer

I put an example of how you can use DomSanitizer here the content is quill

in your component import:

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser'
```

and make functions something like below

```
displayNewsfeed(newsfeed: INewsfeed) {
  this.onenewsfeed = newsfeed[0];
  this.textContent = this.HTMLSant(newsfeed[0].NewsfeedContent);
}

HTMLSant(html:string){
  return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same issue where I'm trying to render an existing html data with Tables in it to quill editor.
I ended up using [clipboards' dangerouslyPasteHTML method](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/clipboard/#dangerouslypastehtml).